# IOS: Custom UITableViewCell - Strange Behaviour after Scrolling

Tags: ios, layout, uitableview

i have a TableView with custom table cells. I add programmatically borders at the bottom of each cell to keep the screendesign layout. Everything is fine, when the App loads the first time. But after scrolling (and scrolling back to the top) multiple border lines are displayed all over the screen.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellProgramm";
ProgrammTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

...

if([object.cellMessageArray[1] isEqualToString:@"wrapper"] || [object.cellMessageArray[1] isEqualToString:@"keynote"] || [object.cellMessageArray[1] isEqualToString:@"break"]) {
UIImageView *lineSeparator = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.bounds.size.height, 1024, 5)];
lineSeparator.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"blind.png" ]];
lineSeparator.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lineSeparator];
}
else if([object.cellMessageArray[1] isEqualToString:@"standard"]) {
UIImageView *lineSeparator = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, cell.bounds.size.height+4, 1024, 1)];
lineSeparator.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"blind.png" ]];
lineSeparator.backgroundColor = [UIColor pxColorWithHexValue:@"eeeeee"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lineSeparator];
}
}
```

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: You are adding UIImageView to cell each time the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method is called. Instead of that, add one UIImageView in your custom cell class (xib/through code) and change its properties.

Comment: handle cell reusability clearly.. It's not strange behaviour. It looks strange for newbies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you scroll a tableview, the cells are reused (`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`) to optimize performance.  In the code above, a `lineSeparator` image view is added to the cell each time the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is invoked.  If the cell is used 5 times, it will have 5 image views added.

One way address this is to remove the `lineSeparator` image view from the cell before it is reused.  This is typically done in the cell's `prepareForReuse` method.

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, add a tag to the `lineSeparator` image view (e.g., `lineSeparator.tag = 100;`

In your cell's class, implement the `prepareForReuse` method.  E.g.:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse{
    UIView *lineSeparatorView = [self.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    [lineSeparatorView removeFromSuperview];
}
```